# Hide destination email or number in facetime

Tags: ios, facetime

I want to make an app that let users make video call using facetime. URL scheme facetime://abc@email.com works but I want to know if I can hide destination email address when making a call?
I want users to make a call via the app only and keep all emails hidden.

Thank you very much.